# Problem with Eclipse plugin in Ubuntu

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, m2eclipse, eclipse-3.5, galileo

I am trying to install the m2eclipse plugin in Eclipse 3.5 on Ubuntu 9.04 Jaunty via the update manager and can't figure out this problem.

After I downloaded and installed the plugin, I restarted Eclipse and checked the Preferences - no Maven there. I double checked the configuration. I can see the m2e plugins I installed in the "Installed Software" tab, but not in the "Plug-ins" tab.

I already read something about deleting the ~/.eclipse folder and restart Eclipse with -clean and tried it, but to no avail. I had no problem doing this under WinXP.

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue? Any help would be appreciated.

PS: I checked the logfile in my workspace. It says something about

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.jface 4 0 2009-08-30 19:13:37.390
!MESSAGE Undefined context while filtering dialog/window contexts
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.core.commands.common.NotDefinedException: Cannot get the parent identifier from an undefined context. org.maven.ide.eclipse.actionSet
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.contexts.Context.getParentId(Context.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.jface.bindings.BindingManager.createFilteredContextTreeFor(BindingManager.java:825)
    at org.eclipse.jface.bindings.BindingManager.recomputeBindings(BindingManager.java:1721)
    at org.eclipse.jface.bindings.BindingManager.contextManagerChanged(BindingManager.java:689)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.contexts.ContextManager.fireContextManagerChanged(ContextManager.java:165)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.contexts.ContextManager.addActiveContext(ContextManager.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.contexts.ContextAuthority.updateContext(ContextAuthority.java:756)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.contexts.ContextAuthority.activateContext(ContextAuthority.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.contexts.ContextService.activateContext(ContextService.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.contexts.SlaveContextService.doActivateContext(SlaveContextService.java:283)
```

but this does appear also for other ActionSet classes (e.g. org.eclipse.jdt.ui.JavaElementCreationActionSet).

EDIT:

```
max@max-laptop:~$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_14"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_14-b08)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 14.0-b16, mixed mode)
```

Comment: What is the output of java -version?

Comment: This happened with all plugins, not only m2eclipse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I solved it. The problem was that Eclipse still tries to write to /opt/eclipse as normal user although it should write to the eclipse user folder in ~/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_3.5.0_1665051554. So I solved my problem with

```
sudo chmod -R a+rw /opt/eclipse
```